# Expressing the area of triangle

Tags: geometry

Right-angled triangle with legs **a** and **b** is divided into two triangles by an altitude to hypotenuse. Express the areas of these triangles using sides a,b. I have an algebraic problem here, because I am unable to express the areas by using purely a and b. I appreciate your help!

[image]

Comment: You labelled the sides as $a^2,b^2.$ I think you just mean $a,b$ and their squares only appear in the two Pythagorean theorm uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$a^2=c_1^2+h^2=c_1(c_1+c_2)=c_1\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$ and $$b^2=c_2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$ so
$$c_1=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ and $$c_2=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ and $$h=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
and we get
$$A_1=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^3b}{a^2+b^2}$$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Areas are $\dfrac{c_1\times h}{2}$ and $\dfrac{c_2\times h}{2}$.

Now write $c_1$, $h$ and $c_2$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ by the relations

$$\tan B = \frac{b}{a} \implies \text{calculate sin B, cos B}$$
$$c_1 = a \cos B $$
$$c_2 = b \sin B $$
$$\frac{h}{c_1} = \frac{b}{a} = \frac{c_2}{h} = \tan B$$

$B$ is the angle opposite to side $b$

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of the areas of similar triangles is equal to the ratio of the squares of their corresponding lengths

The area of the big triangle is $\dfrac{ab}{2}$.

$A_1=\dfrac{ab}{2}\times\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=\dfrac{a^3b}{2(a^2+b^2)}$

$A_2=\dfrac{ab}{2}\times\left(\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=\dfrac{ab^3}{2(a^2+b^2)}$